# class which reads the file content

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to write class which reads the *.csv file and parse it using the pandas library. I'm wondering where I should initialize df.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pandas as pd
import os

class ParseDataBase(object):
        def __init__(self, name_file):
                self.name_file = name_file

        def read_file(self):
                """Read the file concent"""

                try:
                        self.df = pd.read_csv(self.name_file)
                except IndexError:
                        print ("Error: Wrong file name")
                        sys.exit(2)
                return self.df

        def dispaly_file(self):
                print self.df

def main():
        x = ParseDataBase('something.csv')
        x.dispaly_file()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

The above code returns the following error: `'ParseDataBase' object has no attribute 'df'`.

I don't want to pass to many variables while crating the object.

I'm new to object oriented programming, so any comments and hints are highly appreciated!

Comment: What is `self.df`? The error is pretty clear, Python doesn't know what `self.df` is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't assigning `self.df` unless you run `read_file()`, which you aren't.

```
def main():
    x = ParseDataBase('something.csv')
    x.read_file()     
    x.dispaly_file()
```

Answer (score 1):

the attribute `df` gets assigned in the `read_file` method.  You are trying to access that attribute prior to it existing.

I'd do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pandas as pd
import os

class ParseDataBase(object):
        def __init__(self, name_file):
                self.name_file = name_file
                # Change I made to initiate in the init method.
                self.df = self.read_file()

        def read_file(self):
                """Read the file concent"""

                try:
                        self.df = pd.read_csv(self.name_file)
                except IndexError:
                        print ("Error: Wrong file name")
                        sys.exit(2)
                return self.df

        def dispaly_file(self):
                print self.df

def main():
        x = ParseDataBase('something.csv')
        x.dispaly_file()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense. I have one more question. It seems that my exception error is working wrong (except IndexError:) . How may I arise the error in my clase? I'm getting the error: 'File something.csv does not exist'

Comment: What is the full error?  I think it's IOError.  So `except IOError`.

Comment: Yes, it was! Thanks a lot for your help!